# How to stop asynchronous Redux state updates after user logs out?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I have a bug in my web app. I.e. when a user logs in and then quickly logs out, the app will reset the redux state, but the asynchronous actions to fetch user data will still be running. And after the data will be fetched the fresh redux state will still get populated with user data of the previous login. So the question is: is there a way to negate all the actions before logout that are still running? Or there is another solution or other possible errors in my app?

Comment: This is actually a cancelation of ongoing requests. You can achieve this by using redux-sagas with fork or redux-observables. A simpler solution would be to create a middleware that checks if the user is logged in, and if yes then continue with the action reducers, otherwise it will ignore the actions that will populate the store with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with Tasos solution from the comments. I used [this article](https://medium.com/netscape/creating-custom-middleware-in-react-redux-961570459ecb) on creating custom middleware. I also found a similar discussion here: [How to to cancel pending asynchronous actions in React/Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608417/how-to-to-cancel-pending-asynchronous-actions-in-react-redux?rq=1)